# Omnisharp on emacs speed

Tags: emacs, omnisharp

I am running Omnisharp on emacs on a mac. Everything works fine and wonderfully. The only problem is that speed seems to be an issue. Not for intellisense but when moving up and down in lines. (Basic C-n, C-p)

I think it's the suggestions you get on the status bar that slow everything down. They seem to stop my cursor from moving freely so it becomes annoying. Is this async?

Can you disable these status suggestions?

Comment: Would've been better to ask on Emacs.SE. By 'status bar', do you mean the minibuffer? That's like a `help-echo` text property. I'm not sure it can be disabled if that's how it's implemented. Never used omnisharp myself, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably be the Eldoc support, which is indeed not entirely asynchronous yet.

To disable it you can either:
- Turn it off via 'customize' but running 'customize-group','omnisharp', searching for Eldoc and setting it to off.
- Turn it off in Lisp via '(setq omnisharp-eldoc-support nil)'